# Syntax Error With Set Variable In Batch

Tags: batch-file, variables, escaping

So I was messing around with variables, and found out the if i run the following command

```
set var1=|
```

It gives me this error

```
The syntax of this command is incorrect
```

Why does it say that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some symbols may do this. To fix this error you have to use an *escape character*.
So try

```
set var=^|
```

*^* is the escape character you use.

Answer (score 1):

pipe (`|`) is a redirector which takes the output of one command and feeds it into the next. You've not provided a next command.

With all redirectors, if you wannt to use them literally, then you need either

```
set var1=^|
```

where the caret tells `cmd` that the following character is a literal, not part of a command

or

```
set "var1=|"
```

where "quoting the arguments" acts similarly, with the added benefit that any invisible trailing spaces on the line are not included in the valus assigned.